# Sql Server Fill Factor - Restart sql server services

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I changed the Fill Factor option from 1 to 75.

When I run a query that displays the fill Factor I am seeing 75

But I read online that I have to stop and start the sql Server services inorder for this change to be effective. Is that True?

> Blockquote
>   You must stop and restart the SQL Server service for the change to take effect. The new fill factor will be in effect when you see it in the run-value column.
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my 2008r2 enterprise when I changed it via clicking on the instance, right clicking selecting database and changing the fill factor the change did not take effect until I stopped and started the instance.

I tried changing it through TSQL:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'fill factor (%)', '30'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'show advanced options', '0'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Still need a stop/start (bounce) to take effect.